# Word games algorithms, anyone know where can I find them

Tags: algorithm

Hi guys I'm trying to find algorithms of games but not those 3D or 2D, I'm looking for simple games like "guess what word I'm thinking" or any kind of game that only requires basic reading of a text and the user has to choose between some options.

Answer (score 0):

Pangolins is a fun animal guessing game: http://intranet.cs.man.ac.uk/Study_subweb/courses/COMP20010/lab/ex5.html

Hangman is another:
http://pages.intnet.mu/jhbpage/Program/Qbasic/tutorial/Ch19.htm

These were just the first reasonable links I found on Google.